# $L^{2}[-\pi,\pi]$ is unitarily isomorphic to $l^2(\Bbb C)$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, proof-verification, hilbert-spaces, linear-transformations

So I have countable orthonormal basis of $L^2[-\pi,\pi]$ as $\{e^{inx}\}_{n \in \Bbb Z}$ and countable orthonormal basis of $l^2(\Bbb C)$ as $\{a_n\}_{n \in \Bbb Z}$ such that $a_i=\{0,0,...,0,1,0,...0,0,...\}$ where "$1$" is in $i$-th place.

My motive is to find a Linear map $T:L^2[-\pi,\pi] \to l^2(\Bbb C)$ which is one-one , onto, isometry and with the property $TT^\star=T^\star T =I$ where $T^\star$ is adjoint of $T$. (i.e. $<Tx,y>=<x,T^\star y>$)

I define the linear map as $T(e^{inx})=a_n$.

As soon as I do this my worries begin.

- How would I show that $T$ is a linear map?

So let $f,g \in L^2[-\pi,\pi]$. I need to show that $T(f+g)=T(f)+T(g)$.
I think I should write $f$ and $g$ as linear combinations of elements from the set $\{e^{inx}\}_{n \in \Bbb Z}$.Let $f=\sum b_je^{ijx}$ and $g=\sum c_je^{ijx}$.
Then $T(f+g)=?$

Also for a scalar $\alpha \in \Bbb C$ I am struggling to get anywhere in the search of $T(\alpha f)$ to get it equal to $\alpha T(f)$.

I think I might be able to prove the rest that is one-oneness, onto-ness,isometry and the last property "$TT^\star=T^\star T=I$" once I get to prove the linearity.

P.S: Was the way I defined $T$ fine?

Comment: Would note that your definition of $a_i$ is canonically written as $e_i$, otherwise the definition seems alright. Re: showing it's linear, you don't need to worry too much - you've defined the transformation on a basis, so if you extend it naturally from there, you get the linearity for free.

Comment: I chose '$a$' instead of '$e$' because there was already an '$e$' in $e^{inx}$. :D

Comment: Fair enough - I'd personally see that as being more natural, as it alludes to how things should/do match up, but perhaps that's more a matter of preference. The $e_n$ notation is fairly standard for [bases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series#Hilbert_space_interpretation), in any case.

Comment: Okay. :) But I want to have $T(f)$ explicitly. i.e. $T(\sum b_je^{ijx})=?$

Comment: Well, if you want it to be linear, just define it so it matches up -  $T(\sum b_j e^{ijx})=\sum b_j a_j = (b_j)_{j\in\mathbb{Z}}$.

Comment: But I have defined $T(e^{inx})=a_n$ and I want to prove that it is linear. So how can I define like you have done?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34601/discussion-between-r8-and-vikrant-desai).

Comment: Does your $a_n$ make sense when $n$ is negative?

Comment: How is the $T$ you are looking for different from the ordinary Fourier transform?

Comment: @GEdgar You are right I suppose. In the case $n$ is negative, $a_n$ doesn't make sense. But then the '$n$' in $\{e^{inx}\}$ should also be from $\Bbb N$ and we know that $\{e^{inx}\}_{n \in \Bbb Z}$ is the basis for $L^2[-\pi,\pi]$. How should I define the map then?

Comment: @Justpassingby Is there any connection between this $T$ and the Fourier transform? If it's true, then I have no idea about it.

Comment: @Vikrant Desai surely the map $T:L^2\to l^2:f\mapsto\left(\frac1{2\pi}\int f(t)\exp(-int)dt\right)_{n\in\mathbb Z}$ satisfies your requirement?

Comment: Two possibilities: define $l^2$ using index set $\mathbb Z$.  If that is unacceptable, show that $l^2$ with index set $\mathbb N$ is unitarily isometric to $l^2$ with index set $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @Justpassingby oh great!! I will check it whether it satisfies all the conditions given for a map to be Unitarily Isomorphic. :)

Comment: @GEdgar Okay!!!

Comment: @Vikrant the fact that it is unitary is known as Parseval's identity https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval's_identity

Comment: @Justpassingby I didn't understand how it is unitary as the Parseval's identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map

$$T:L^2\to l^2:f\mapsto\left(a_n=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int f(t)\exp(-int)dt\right)_{n\in\mathbb Z}$$

sends any square integrable function to the sequence of its Fourier coefficients, so we have

$$\eqalignno{f(x)&=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}a_n\exp(inx)&(1)}$$

for almost every $x$.

The fact that $T$ is an isometry is known as Parseval's identity:

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}|a_n|^2=\int|f(t)|^2dt$$

(the LHS is the square of the $l^2$ norm of the sequence $(a_n)_n$ while the RHS is the square of the $L^2$ norm of the function $f$)

Between Hilbert spaces, saying that an invertible linear map is isometric or unitary is one and the same thing. By definition, a linear map $U$ is unitary if it is the inverse of its adjoint ($UU^*=I=U^*U$) but by the definition of the adjoint this is the same as saying that $(Ux,Uy)_{l^2}=(x,y)_{L^2}$ for all $x,y\in L^2,$ i.e., $U$ is unitary if and only if it preserves the scalar product.

Now maps that preserve the norm automatically preserve the scalar product because the norm in an inner product space can be expressed as a function of the scalar product; this is known as *polarization* and in complex inner product spaces it takes the form

$$\langle x,y\rangle=\frac14\left(\|x+y\|^2-\|x-y\|^2+i\|x+iy\|^2-i\|x-iy\|^2\right).$$

Actually, in our case the explicit form of $T^*$ as a mapping from sequences $(a_n)_n$ to functions $f$ is given by formula (1).

Comment: Great. But how is it unitary? I mean the "$TT^\star = T^\star T=I$" part.

Comment: Between Hilbert spaces, unitary and isometric are synonyms. Sometimes "isometry" is defined as "preserving the norm" and "unitary" is defined as "preserving the inner product", but the inner product can be expressed as a function of the norm using the polarization identity.

Comment: Oh! But still if I wish to find $T^\star$ then what should I do? My proof demands showing that property.

Comment: I have made that part of the answer slightly more explicit.

Comment: Thank you very much for enlightening me on this topic! :)

Answer (score 1):

Note that it is not a priori clear that a map satisfying $T(e^{inx}) = a_n$ exists. In fact, there exists infinitely many different linear maps $T \colon L^2([-\pi,\pi]) \rightarrow \ell_2(\mathbb{Z})$ but only one of those maps will be the map you want so it is not enough to say "we define $T$ by $T(e^{inx}) = a_n$".

In linear algebra, given an (algebraic) basis $(v_{\alpha})_{\alpha \in I}$ of some vector space $V$ and some choice of elements $(w_{\alpha})_{\alpha \in I}$ in another vector space $W$, there is a unique linear map $T \colon V \rightarrow W$ satisfying $T(v_{\alpha}) = w_{\alpha}$ for all $\alpha \in I$. If $(v_{\alpha})_{\alpha \in I}$ are merely linearly independent but do not form a basis, there exists many linear maps $T \colon V \rightarrow W$ satisfying $T(v_{\alpha}) = w_{\alpha}$ for all $\alpha \in I$ (each obtained by extending $(v_{\alpha})_{\alpha \in I}$ to a basis of $V$ and defining $T$ arbitrary on the extra vectors). In your case, the sequence $\{e^{inx}\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ do not form an algebraic basis for $L^2([0,2\pi])$ so there are many linear maps satisfying $T(e^{inx})=a_n$.

However, if you work in a Hilbert space $V$ with a countable orthonormal system $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ and you choose some sequence of elements $\{w_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ in another Hilbert space $W$, then trying to mimick the linear algebra construction and taking into account the topology, you are lead to defining a map $T \colon V \rightarrow W$ by

$$ T \left( \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} c_i v_i \right) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} c_i w_i. $$

Any element $v \in V$ can be **uniquely** written as $v = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} c_i v_i$ where $(c_i)_{i=1}^{\infty} \in \ell_2(\mathbb{N})$ but a priori there is no guarantee that the right hand side will converge in $W$. However, if the $\{w_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ are an orthonormal system for $W$, you can check that the right hand indeed converges and so you have a well-defined map between $V$ and $W$ which is obviously linear. You can check that $T$ will be an isometry and the inverse of $T$ will be given by

$$ T^{-1} \left( \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} c_i w_i \right) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} c_i v_i $$

which will also be $T^{*}$.

Comment: In your case, the countable orthonormal systems are index by $\mathbb{Z}$ rather than by $\mathbb{N}$ but it makes no difference in the argument.

Comment: an orthogonal linear map on a Hilbert space defined by $T(\phi_n) = \Phi_n$ always converges in the $||.||_2$ sense, since it preserves the norm ? (so that it is a bounded linear operator)

Comment: @user1952009 I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: I was not really asking, I was trying to extract the main argument from your answer. and because $\{e^{i n x}\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ is dense and orthogonal in $L_2([-\pi;\pi])$, we get that $L_2([-\pi;\pi])$ and $l_2(\mathbb{Z})$ are isomorphic (in the hilbert space sense)

Comment: Is working on $l^2(\Bbb Z)$ and $l^2(\Bbb C)$ one and the same?

Comment: @levap why does $\{e^{inx}\}_{n \in \Bbb Z}$ not form the basis for "$L^2[-\pi,\pi]$"? (I think you mistakenly wrote $L^2[0,2\pi]$)